# matplotlib: customize the choice of colormap for a plotting function

Tags: python

Because there are many different colormaps, I'd like to set one parameter in the function below to be the name of colormap, which allows the users to choose their favorite colormap such as 'viridis', 'plasma', 'winter', 'cool' and so on.

```
def my_plot(cm_name):

    # setup the normalization and the colormap
    nValues = np.array(np.linspace(1, 50, 50))
    normalize = mcolors.Normalize(vmin=nValues.min(), vmax=nValues.max())
    colormap = cm.cm_name

    # setup the colorbar
    sm = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=normalize, cmap=colormap)
    sm.set_array(nValues)

    # below is the code for plotting
```

However, when I define the plotting function as shown above and when I call `my_plot(viridis)`, an error message pops out:

```
NameError: name 'viridis' is not defined
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function can only accept a string as a parameter, but `cm.cm_name` is an attribute. You cannot access the attribute `viridis` of `cm` by writing `cm.'viridis'`.

This is the perfect use case for `getattr`, which takes an **object** and a **string** and returns the *attribute of that object whose name is the same as the string passed to* `getattr`.

Change the line

```
colormap = cm.cm_name
```

to

```
colormap = getattr(cm, cm_name)
```

and call your function with a string (not a variable) representing the colormap:

```
my_plot('viridis')
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the colormap should be a `string`, and thus you need to call it like `my_plot("viridis")`. If you omit the quotation marks, python thinks that `viridis` is the name of a variable that you want to pass in, and then complains that you haven't told it what this variable is.